# How to interpret operation names such as FP_COMP_OPS_EXE.X87

Tags: floating-point, profiling, intel-vtune

I use Intel VTuen to collect instructions of a program and I get results like

```
FP_COMP_OPS_EXE:MMX
FP_COMP_OPS_EXE:SSE_DOUBLE_PRECISION
FP_COMP_OPS_EXE:SSE_FP
FP_COMP_OPS_EXE:SSE_FP_PACKED
FP_COMP_OPS_EXE:SSE_FP_SCALAR
FP_COMP_OPS_EXE:SSE_SINGLE_PRECISION
FP_COMP_OPS_EXE:SSE2_INTEGER
FP_COMP_OPS_EXE:X87
```

In the name of each type of operation, I know "FP" represents floating point, "OPS" means operations, but what does "COMP" represent? My initial understanding is that "COMP" means comparison, is that true? If it is, what does comparison here mean?

Answer (score 0):

An excerpt from a reference description on [this page](http://www.hpc.ut.ee/dokumendid/ips_xe_2015/vtune_amplifier_xe/documentation/en/help/reference/pmn/events/fp_comp_ops_exe.html) (which I found by googling FP_COMP_OPS_EXE) says that a certain command "Counts the number of FP Computational Uops Executed." Therefore I believe you could expand it like this:

- FP: Floating Point
- COMP: Computational
- OPS: Operations
- EXE: Executed